# Is $MSB$ of permanent and certifying half number of witnesses easy?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, permanent

1. Can there be a $P$ algorithm to decide if number of perfect matchings is at least $(n!/2)+1$ for a bipartite graph on $n+n$ vertices?
2. Can there be a $P$ algorithm to decide if number of witnesses exactly $2^n$ for a $SAT$ formula with $2n$ variables

At least are any of above problems in $PH$? Is there any consequence if they are so?